# RowReorder extension does not save position of the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables 1.10 and try to understand why this new function - rowReorder - does not work as it should.

In fact, the plugin itself works perfectly: I can easy drag & drop the entire row. However, it does not save new position of the row so I always get the initial order (which is useless then).

Can you please let me know what's wrong here? I use a very basic code here:

```
table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
     data: jsondata,
    aoColumns: col_label_group,
    fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        nRow.setAttribute('id', iDisplayIndex);  
    },
     rowReorder: {
        selector: 'tr'
    }
})
```

See example on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frederic123/wrhh3tbu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using objects as a data source use [`rowReorder.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.dataSrc) option to specify which property holds the sequence number.

```js
rowReorder: {
     selector: 'tr',
     dataSrc: 'r'
},
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrhh3tbu/3/) for code and demonstration.